# Facebook Canvas Not loading Url Even if it has SSL

Tags: facebook, ssl, canvas, facebook-javascript-sdk

I was trying to do some sample facebook canvas application,

I have created the app in Facebook developer and created new platform in side facebook canvas.

I have give Canvas secure Url as https://www.google.co.in/, https://www.audiotube.com/, https://bitbucket.org

SO I opened the app page which is not loading the data

https://apps.facebook.com/521031588051793

But If I use other https websites means It will load for ex. https://eatwater.co.uk

Comment: If I look in the Console it say: "Refused to display 'https://www.audiotube.com/' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'SAMEORIGIN'."

Answer (score 1):

X-Frame-Options is a relatively new web feature that prevents malicious attacks like [framesniffing](http://www.infosecurity-magazine.com/news/framesniffing-with-chrome-safari-and-internet/) or [clickjacking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clickjacking). New development frameworks such as MVC5 provide out of the box support for this. If the X-FrameOptions response header is set to `SAMEORIGIN` it means the page can only be included in an `iframe` in a web site that is in the same domain with the requested page.

other options are:

`DENY`: no page can use the requested page as an iframe.
`ALLOW-FROM: http://www.example.com`: only allows from the `example.com` domain. have in mind though this is not supported in chrome and safari browsers.

So to answer your question, the sites you are including in your canvas app are requested by `apps.facebook.com` to fill an `iframe`, and the browser blocks the request because these sites' configuration is set to `SAMEORIGIN`.

take a look at this [blog post](http://www.iambacon.co.uk/blog/mvc5-prevents-your-website-being-loaded-in-an-iframe).